# iSCSI/FCoE/FC Throughput Formulas

Tags: san

Many references online mention you should use 10Gb links (HBA/CNA) when designing your SAN.
However, is there a formula or calculation that can provide the amount of bandwidth that is really required when using a SAN-based protocol. i.e can you relate IOPs to actual network traffic.

Thanks,

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

*IOPs* depend mainly on throughput capabilities and latencies of your storage hardware and (to a much lesser extent) latencies in your network. In other words, you can't "translate" a certain infrastructure to IOPs (you can make an educated guess though).

However, you need to design your SAN to manage the *bandwidth* you require. Once you exceed the bandwidth in your infrastructure, IOPs simply stop on that level and latencies skyrocket.

If you have a concrete workload you can try to calculate bandwidth from IOPs but that may or may not match reality.

For maximum iSCSI port throughput, you can multiply [the efficiency for TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame#Bandwidth_efficiency) over standard Ethernet (94.9%) or using 9k jumbo frames (99.1%) with the nominal Ethernet port rate to get a good figure. Overhead from iSCSI itself is pretty much neglectable (except for very high IOP figures and very low actual bandwidth) and decent switches will be very close to the theoretical maximum.

Native Fibre Channel is a bit harder to grasp due to its very rough nominal speeds (including L0 overhead, unlike Ethernet), but you can get an idea [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interface_bit_rates#Storage).

In SANs you need to very specifically look into the (present and future) workloads. Aggregating links may come as scaling path but you need to be aware that an aggregated link cannot transport flows faster than any one of its physical links. In other words: aggregating links increases *overall bandwidth* but *it doesn't increase bandwidth for any one flow*.

Four aggregated 10G links support one or more (ideally four) separate 10G flows but they don't support a single 40G flow. That is because each connection is always forwarded through the same physical port pair - depending on the hardware and its configuration, by MAC addresses, IP addresses, or IP and L4 port combinations.

Also, you need to consider that in a SAN, multiple bandwidth-demanding workloads can run at the same time. You may be able to separate them in time windows (e.g. running backups during slow night times) but if there's a potential need to run them in parallel, you need to be prepared. Interconnects can very easily become bottlenecks (which you generally want to avoid in a SAN). Depending on your requirements and your budget, you need to find a viable concept.

So, you need to plan the network very carefully and consider the future demand for workloads within the lifetime of the network. Upgradable switches provide more headroom, aggregating links may have severe limitations. You can start cheap but then you may need to replace hardware before the planned service life ends.

Comment: Thanks ,but the question is still how do you size the network, when do you go for 40gb over 10gb etc ie for ISCSI let’s say.

Comment: You need to examine your workloads. When they demand 40G you need your network to provide the speed.

Comment: But you need to design before hand hence looking for how this is typically design/calc from a storage arch standpoint 

Comment: Yes. You need to take a crystal ball and look at what might be coming at you within the next x years. That is your design base for the network.

Comment: There's no one cook book for doing this. It's analysis, intuition and experience.

Comment: that's why ability to scale is (or should be) an important aspect of your design, especially if you are unsure about workloads.

Comment: ok im sure there would of been a calculation like is used across most design. Maybe I was wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to calculate. You *can* calculate a maximum bandwidth between any two points on your network. You *can* use a list of required bandwidths to build a network for. However, there are other requirements such as reliability, scalability, management, cost that you *can't all put in a single formula*. If you add your requirements and a design concept to your question we can try looking over it.